# condition to randomly replace a character

Tags: python, random, range

I have a sequence, to which I replace 5 characters at random, the problem I have is how to replace the character at random, this in some cases is replaced by itself, how can I put a conditionality so that for example if the character to replace matches With "a" it is only replaced by "b,c,do e", if the character to replace matches "b" it is only replaced by "a,c,do e"...

```
import random
s1='ecaaaeadddeeecbddddb'
print(s1)
change_locs = set(sample(range(len(s1)), 5))
changed = (random.choice(['a','b','c','d','e',]) if i in change_locs else c for i,c in 
enumerate(s1))
s2=''.join(changed)
print(s2)
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be a more 'pythonic' way of doing this with a list comprehension, but the following code is fairly self-explanatory and should work fast enough for most purposes:

```
def mutate_string(s, alphabet, n):
    # Randomly change n characters in s to different
    # characters selected from alphabet
    from random import sample, randint
    change_locs = set(sample(range(len(s)), n))
    result = ''
    for (position, ch) in enumerate(s):
        if position in change_locs:
            # Randomly choose an alphabet index from 0 to two
            # less than the length of alphabet
            p = randint(0, len(alphabet)-2)
            # If this alphabet character matches the original
            # character, use the last alphabet character
            # instead
            if alphabet[p] == ch:
                p = -1
            result += alphabet[p]
        else:
            # Not changing this character, so just
            # copy it across
            result += ch
    return result
```

The basic idea is to swap characters by selecting a new character from all but the last member of the alphabet. If the new character matches the old one, use the last character of the alphabet instead.

I haven't tested this thoroughly, but can see no reason why it shouldn't work properly.

```
>>> mutate_string('aaabbbcccdddeee', 'abcde', 5)
'aeababcbdddddee'
>>>
```